# Couldn't start MySQL! while starting XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

I am new in Ubuntu, I installed XAMPP in my Ubuntu 10.04. When I start XAMPP it says MySQL couldn't start.

Here is my terminal ouput:

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

And then as I go to `http://localhost`, I got stuck on the XAMPP splash-screen, nothing happens if I choose language.

Comment: Did you check the log file? 
    tail /var/log/mysql.log

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer. First completly uninstall the lampp and then reinstall it. Before uninstalling, stop the lampp using the command:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

and then uninstall/remove it using the command

```
rm -rf /opt/lampp
```

then reinstall it.

Comment: You are going to remove whole code if user don't know much about rm.

Answer (score 30):

This Worked For me as a Charm. [I used Ubuntu 12.04 and Xampp]

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf

sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql

sudo chown -hR root:root /opt/lampp
```

& Now Start Your Xampp

Comment: `sudo chown -hR root:root /opt/lampp` works for me, instead of `sudo chown -hR root/opt/lampp`, like @this.lau_ said

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work for me. I am using ubuntu 14.04 by the way.

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 8):

It might just be that the `/opt/lampp` doesn't have the right permissions. Before reinstalling everything, try running the commands below, it worked for me:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql
sudo chown -hR root:root /opt/lampp
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the version where the MySQL is not started with the command `rm -rf /opt/lampp`
and the command:

```
tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Replace `xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz` with your file name. After restarting your lampp, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have completely removed your old lampp instance. Please remove it and install lampp once again.

Comment: no i had completely removed the old one. i searched alot in google, tried many ways but nothing worked. Pls help me.

Comment: I found answer, First completly uninstall the lampp and install it once more it will work .
Before uninstalling stop the lampp using the command

/opt/lampp/lampp stop

 and then uninstall it using the command
 
rm -rf /opt/lampp

 then try to install it once more .. it will work properly..

Answer (score 1):

It might be the right `permissions` problem. Some solutions guide you to set it to **`777`** which is not recommended.  Try to set it to original permissions as installed. (especially after you restore from a tar without preserving the permissions)

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop

sudo chown nobody.root /opt/lampp/var/mysql/cdcol /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql        /opt/lampp/var/mysql/phpmyadmin -R

sudo chown nobody.nogroup /opt/lampp/var/mysql/yourdbname -R

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue. Always check for the error log before proceeding to find the root cause. Sometimes it could be file system space issue. In my case it was "/" file system was full. After clearing some space I was able to start the services without issues.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Well, to be fair, if the issue was insufficient space, this would be an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP started successfully on my side, but still got stuck at spalsh screen.
It was solved by giving permission to lang.tmp file

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/lang.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your previous MySQL installation might be blocking your MySQL from the xampp bundle. I also had the same problem. Just uninstall the previous MySQL. Open the terminal(Ctrl ALt T) and paste the following code:

First stop XAMPP:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

Uninstall MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Start XAMPP:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```