# MySQL Database cannot start on XAMPP for Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

All of a sudden I am encountering this problem on my mac. I cant start my MySQL Database. I can only start my ProFTPD and Apache Web Server.

This is the application log:

```
Starting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
```

I have even did some research through stackoverflow. First i tried to end the process through my activity monitor by i couldnt find the keyword sql on the filter search area. The second method i tried was adding the `unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
but that didnt even worked for me.

Can i know how to solve this problem. Helps would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Mostly this happens when a previous process is running already. just go to activity monitor search for mysql and terminate it... then start the mysql database again. will definitely work.

Answer (score 36):

```
#1. Open XAMPP Installation Directory
#2. Open "etc" Folder
#3. Find "my.cnf" file and open it in any text editor
#4. Change Port from 3306 to 3307 (if you have installed skype or other apps)
#5. Add "innodb_force_recovery=1" under "myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M"
#6. Save "my.cnf" file
#7. Restart Mysql Server By Your Terminal by command:
"sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start" 

You Get A message "Starting MySQL SUCCESS! "
```

Comment: but keep in mind that you will get `Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0` error when you try to insert data into table  so you have to restore it to `0`

Answer (score 12):

For me, Xampp Control panel was not launching, and in Stackoverflow some where it was mentioned to add Read / Write for every one on every file of xampp, when I did that. It allowed me to launch xampp control panel but mysql was not starting.

Later I debuged and found that `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf` should not be writeable by everyone, mysql will ignore my.cnf if it is for everyone. I changed the permission to read only for this file, and able to start mysql server

Answer (score 7):

I Know this post was originally posted last year, but I just had the same problem and I found the solution for me. So here it is, just in case this can help somebody else.

I tried all the suggestions I found online, including trying to terminate MySQL on the activity monitor, but then I realized that when you download/upgrade XAMPP - MySQL, the option to automatically start MySQLserver on Startup is ON. You need to turn it off. Here is what you do:

Go **System Preferences** and click on the Mysql icon, You should get this window:

[image: MySQL Window]

Uncheck that option. You will be asked for your password. After you are done with that, restart your computer and the problem should be fixed.

I hope that help somebody who is as confused as I was. lol ✌

Answer (score 6):

I just solve the answer by going to the activity monitor and search for sql under all process and terminate it. then i restart my mac and now my sql database is working great for me.

Answer (score 4):

Xampp Control Panel> Manage Server> Mysql Database > Configure > change the port from 3306 to 3307

At least it worked for me in mac.

Answer (score 1):

For me using macOS Catalina, I had to delete this 2 files then quit and restart the manager-osx:

- MyName-MacBook-Pro.local.err
- tc.log

The folder path is this: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var

Note: the 2 files were automatically regenerated after I start and Apache and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If mysql is not starting in xampp, it might be a port conflict issue. Mysql run by default on port 3306. you need to check if another application is occupying that port. use following command to check app occupying a port

```
lsof -nP -i4TCP:3306
```

if you find an application occupying that port, stop the application and restart xampp. As an alternative, you can go to php.ini file or click configure in the dropdown and change the mysql port to 3307

Answer (score 0):

I spent whole day trying to resolve this issue. Changing the port no from 3306 to 3307 worked for me. Simply open the configure module and change the port number. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In case this may help. I followed all the steps above still nothing worked for me. And I follow this article [MySQL database won't start in xampp](https://medium.com/@panayiotisgeorgiou/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx-ef559b00dfef) and it worked. what is says is:

**Steps**

1. **Open terminal and type**

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

   and then put in your password
2. **Then type**

   ```
   ps aux | grep mysql
   ```
3. **You will need to get the process id of mysql. There should be number near the top, something like 739 or 8827** (in my case I got 74689, just look after *mysql* or *_mysql* process id)
4. Kill the process using

   ```
   kill -9 {process id}
   ```

   this should look something like this: kill -9 739
5. Restart MySQL in manager-osx

If any of the above don’t work, This should work:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested solutions above however none worked for me. So I uninstalled XAMPP and then reinstalled it and so now MySQL server starts up ok.